# JQuery Module Pattern: On click toggle function not working using

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click when I try to access method "dropDownUserInfo" it gives an error [Can not read property 'slideToggle' of undefined]

Code:

```
(function(){
var homePage = {
        init: function(){
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvent();
        },            
        cacheDom: function(){
            this.$userInfo = $('.user-info a');
            this.$userContent = $('.user-info-content');
        },
        bindEvent: function(){                
            this.$userInfo.on('click', this.dropDownUserInfo);
        },
        dropDownUserInfo: function(){                                                                                                                     
            this.$userContent.slideToggle(500);
            this.$userInfo.toggleClass('active');   
       },          
    }
    homePage.init();
})();
```

Comment: Need to see HTML as well and please present it as a [mcve] by clicking the bracket button:`<>`

Comment: check whether the $userContent is having the correct DOM element

Answer (score 1):

`this` in event handler method `dropDownUserInfo` function will refer to DOM element which raised the event.

You can use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set its context.

```
this.$userInfo.on('click', this.dropDownUserInfo.bind(this));
```

*Here is an example*

```js
(function() {
  var homePage = {
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvent();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.$button = $('button');
    },
    bindEvent: function() {
      this.$button.on('click', this.buttonClick.bind(this));
      this.$button.on('click', this.buttonClick2);
    },
    buttonClick: function() {
      this.$button.toggleClass('active');
    },
    buttonClick2: function() {
      console.clear();
      this.$button.text('active'); //Will throw error
    }
  }
  homePage.init();
})();
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in function `dropDownUserInfo` refers to the object which calls the event. So you can change your code like this:

```
this.$userInfo.on('click', this.dropDownUserInfo.bind(this))
```